# Simulate pressing Ctrl + right Shift in notepad

Tags: python

I have a function that opens a text file then pressing `Ctrl + A` to select all the contents

```
def open_in_notepad(file_path):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe', file_path])
        os.system(f'powershell -command "& {{$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; $wshell.AppActivate(\'Notepad\'); Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; $wshell.SendKeys(\'^a\') }}"')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)
```

How can I simulate pressing `Ctrl + right Shift`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keyboard module (https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) to simulate button presses